# How to display (passed by bundle) strings using TextView

Tags: java, android

How to display string values from this code

```
  TextView textViewDisplayResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view_display_result);

 String allChecked = "", answer = "";
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

    if (bundle != null) {
        if (bundle.containsKey("KEY_ALL_CHECKED"))
            allChecked = bundle.getString("KEY_ALL_CHECKED");

        answer = bundle.getString("KEY_ANSWER");
```

in here

```
textViewDisplayResult.setText();
```

UPDATED POST (methods `checkAnswers` and `allAnswerChecked` from MainActivity)

```
 private boolean checkAnswers() {
    for (boolean radioAnswer : answer) {
        if (!radioAnswer) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

private boolean allAnswersChecked() {
    for (boolean radioAnswer : isAnswered) {
        if (!radioAnswer) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

And method `buttonCheckAnswer`

```
 buttonCheckAnswer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!allAnswersChecked())
                intent.putExtra("KEY_ALL_CHECKED", R.string.text_not_checked);

            if (checkAnswers())
                intent.putExtra("KEY_ANSWER", R.string.Good_answer);

            else
                intent.putExtra("KEY_ANSWER", R.string.Wrong_answer);



            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

`AnswerActivity.java`

```
public class AnswerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_answer);
    TextView textViewDisplayResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view_display_result);


    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (bundle != null) {
        if (bundle.containsKey("KEY_ALL_CHECKED"))

            textViewDisplayResult.setText(bundle.getString("KEY_ALL_CHEC‌​KED") + " "+ bundle.getString("KEY_ANSWER"));
        }

    }
```

}

Comment: textViewDisplayResult.setText(allChecked + answer);

Comment: Hi, in this case I get `null`

Comment: bundle.getString("KEY_ALL_CHECKED") and bundle.getString("KEY_ANSWER"); are giving you null

Comment: using your suggested code I get warnings `allChecked` and `answer` never accessed

Comment: can you show the complete code where you are getting values for allChecked , answer and setting in your textview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set text directly using.

```
textViewDisplayResult.setText(bundle.getString("KEY_ALL_CHECKED") + " "+ bundle.getString("KEY_ANSWER"));
```

Comment: Hi, using this code I get warnings `allChecked` and `answer` `never accessed`

Comment: yes you have to remove line

 String allChecked = "", answer = "";

Comment: also remove     allChecked = bundle.getString("KEY_ALL_CHECKED");

        answer = bundle.getString("KEY_ANSWER");

Comment: at final Replace :=> **String allChecked = "", answer = "";
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

    if (bundle != null) {
        if (bundle.containsKey("KEY_ALL_CHECKED"))
            allChecked = bundle.getString("KEY_ALL_CHECKED");

        answer = bundle.getString("KEY_ANSWER");**

=======
with :=>


   **Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

    if (bundle != null) {
        if (bundle.containsKey("KEY_ALL_CHECKED"))
          textViewDisplayResult.setText(bundle.getString("KEY_ALL_CHECKED") + " "+ bundle.getString("KEY_ANSWER"));**

Comment: Now I get `null` displayed :(

Comment: Upendra, but where is value "KEY_ANSWER" in Bundle? We use it in `textViewDisplay....` but we don't have any `"KEY_ANSWER"` earlier in `Bundle`

Comment: haven't you passed bundle from previous activity?? if you passed that than it will directly get value for KEY_ANSWER and KEY_ALL_CHEC‌​KED.

Comment: Updated my post with whole `AnswerActivity.java` for you to have a clear view on this issue. Or maybe you ask about sth else?

Comment: you are using **R.string.Good_answer** it is an id so you have to write at there **getResources().getString(R.string.Good_answer)** and same for **R.string.text_not_checked** and **R.string.Wrong_answer**

Comment: Where exactly I have to write `getResources().getString...`?

Comment: **intent.putExtra("KEY_ALL_CHECKED", R.string.text_not_checked);**   replace with 
**intent.putExtra("KEY_ALL_CHECKED", getResources().getString(R.string.text_not_checked));**
 
**intent.putExtra("KEY_ANSWER", R.string.Good_answer);**

replace with  
**intent.putExtra("KEY_ANSWER", getResources().getString(R.string.Good_answer));**

**intent.putExtra("KEY_ANSWER", R.string.Wrong_answer);**
replace with  
**intent.putExtra("KEY_ANSWER", getResources().getString(R.string.Wrong_answer));**

Comment: Ok Upendra, I think we are almost there. Now when I run it I get `"null Wrong answer'` or `"null Good answer'` but I never get `"text not checked'` even when I should have.

Comment: just try to pass hard coded string at replace of getResources().getString(R.string.text_not_checked)

Comment: Upendra, when debugging I get `savedInstanceState=null` in line `if (bundle !=null.....` ,maybe this is any help?

Comment: I've changed to `" intent.putExtra("KEY_ALL_CHECKED", "text_not_checked");` but no luck :(

Comment: please change variable "KEY_ALL_CHECKED" to anything else.. or copy and paste same variable name wherever you used

Comment: Hello Upendra. Going through my posts I came across your messages and thought maybe you could help me on this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43997655/zoom-in-out-the-whole-page-layout. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: have you get solution of this question?? if yes than mark it as answer and upvote so other can get easily get solutions..

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

```
String answer = bundle.getString("KEY_ANSWER");
textViewDisplayResult.setText(answer);
```

Comment: Yes, but I also have to display other text "KEY_ALL_CHECKED"

Comment: Are you sure you're sending the data to the correct activity? Check in the origin activity if the values are setted in the intent

Answer (score 0):

You can set bunlde values in text view like this:

```
textViewDisplayResult.setText(answer);
textViewDisplayResult.setText(allChecked);
```

Comment: then debug your code, may be "answer"/"alChecked" doesn't contains values.